# Authenticate to Google Admin Directory API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-directory-api

(I've reviewed similar questions on SO, however none of the suggestions have worked for me)

I have an API service that runs on Google App Engine (on the Google Cloud Platform). I need to authenticate to the Google Admin Directory API so that I can create groups on our GSuite domain.

I initially tried implicit authorisation by following the guide to [Obtaining and providing service account credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually), but I think that may be limited to communication between apps that are running on Google App Engine. My understanding is that talking to a Google API outside of App Engine requires OAuth 2.0, so I've set things up as follows:

I've set up the App Engine default service account, and I've granted domain wide delegation to the account from within the Google Cloud Platform. I've also delegated domain-wide authority from the GSuite side, by following this guide - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

I've generated a P12 key for the service account. I'm then setting up credentials and using them to instantiate a Google Admin Directory client API as follows:

```
final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);

final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

/** Email of the Service Account */
final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "my_service_account_email@appspot.gserviceaccount.com";
final String USER_EMAIL = "myGsuiteAdmin@mydomain.com";

/** Path to the Service Account's Private Key file */
final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE = "myPath.p12";

String p12Password = "notasecret";

ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
InputStream keyFileStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE);

if (keyFileStream == null){
throw new Exception("Key File Not Found.");
}

keystore.load(keyFileStream, p12Password.toCharArray());
PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("privatekey", p12Password.toCharArray());

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
    .setServiceAccountUser(USER_EMAIL)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(pk)
    .build();


Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null)
.setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.Group group = new Group();
group.setEmail("test@mydomain.com");
group.setName("test_group");
group.setDescription("test_group_desc");

Group googleGroup = directory.groups().insert(group).execute();

// error on the line above (403: Not Authorized to access this resource/api - forbidden)
```

I get an error on the final line, where I try to create a new group:

```
Group googleGroup = directory.groups().insert(group).execute();
```

> ```
> 403: Not Authorized to access this resource/api - forbidden
> ```

What do I need to do to successfully authenticate?

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is to follow the documentation.

1. Do not use an App Engine Service Account. Create a new Service Account.
2. Do not use P12 (PFX) as they are deprecated. Most APIs no longer support them. Use JSON credential file.
3. You need to delegate Domain-Wide Authority to the Service Account.
4. Using the Service Account credentials you impersonate another User that has domain superadmin privilege and who has logged in at least once into G Suite and accepted the terms and conditions.

[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation)

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley, I followed your comment to my other (related) question. I made some progress which is why I'm posting a new question. I'll try creating a new service account and see if that works.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow - Using an App Engine Service Account caused your first problem. Make sure that you first create credentials using the service account in your code. Then impersonate to create new credentials. Also, don't change anything when creating the new service account.

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow - If you get really stuck package up your code and send it to me. I will help you debug it. I am currently spending a lot of time on OAuth, credentials, etc. so that I really understand all the nuances of Google authentication. Real world problems are usually very good test cases.

Comment: Hi @John Hanley. I set up a new service account with domain-wide authority. In Google Admin console, I gave it API client access and added the scope for creating groups(https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group). I use the service account to impersonate a new GSuite superadmin user, using JSON credentials.  (I tried the orginal GSuite superadmin account but it didn't work). I added the new superadmin to the 'Groups Admin' role in the Google Admin console, and I logged into GSuite with the new account and accepted the T&Cs. I still get a 403. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Are you saying that you modified the service account? That was the point that you should not do. Just create it. The privileges comes from the account that you are impersonating which has superadmin rights to G Suite. Delete the service account and start over. Think of the service account as a noop that is just a placeholder so that you can assume the identity of the G Suite user. You assign the scopes to the G Suite user and not the service account.

Comment: Thanks, no I created a new service account

Comment: Hi @John Hanley we can chat here 
 - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185394/google-admin-api

Comment: Did this issue ever get resolved. It's 2023 and this problem still exists in one shape or another and the google documentation is terrible. this github pretty much describes what I'm experiencing the only difference is that I'm using Java not Node
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1884#issuecomment-1062354602